# Как убрать пространство между title(NavigationView) и верхней границей экрана

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Я хочу убрать пространство между navigationTitle и верхней границей экрана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел решение где прячут заголовок полностью, но так и не нашел, возможно ли оставить заголовок и убрать эту пустоту.

Comment: Почему не подходит убрать заголовок полностью и использовать вместо него `Text`, который можно поставить где угодно и как нужно настроить?

Comment: Интересно, есть ли такая возможность, просто к чему все эти костыли, если это реализуется в NavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Вы о Large title. Делается это просто, но не совсем очевидно:

```
// При установке заголовка
.navigationBarTitle("Image2Base64", displayMode: .inline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Эта пустота появляется для того, чтобы при скролле Large Title мог стать Inline - это стандартный элемент.
Можно использовать вариант [VAndrJ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200452/vandrjJ), но тогда  заголовок будет маленьким и прибит к самому верху экрана.
Можно не использовать bar Title, добавить Text нужного размера. Но если есть навигация между окнами, то скрытие navigation bar - создаст сложности, чтобы вернуться на предыдущий экран.

```
struct BarView: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.red //
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Large Title")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)) // здесь можно выставить нужные отступы
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }

    }
}}
```

[image: Как это выглядит в симуляторе]